# How to set a option id in collection_select in Ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper, collection-select

Recently, I met an issue on how to set an option id in collection_select. because I want to use some js to hide some options .

For example there are 2 modules, user belongs to Tenant.When I click the radio box tenant1 , I want for the page to only show the users in tenant1.

This is what I write for the check box but how to do the same things for selecting?

**js**

```
function toggleTenants() {
  $('#tenant_panel input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    const selectedTenantId = $(this).val();
    $('.checkbox[data-tenant-id]').hide();
    $('.checkbox[data-tenant-id="' + selectedTenantId + '"]').show();
  })
}
```

**Application helper**

```
  collection_check_boxes(object, method, collection.all, :id , value_method) do |c|
    content_tag(:div, :class => 'checkbox', "data-tenant-id" => c.object.tenant_id) do
      c.label("data-value" => c.value) { c.check_box + " " + c.text }
    end
  end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't know whether its possible with `collection_select` but it achievable usning ruby's `select` view helper. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22801275/2570423) is an example.

Comment: @mehedi thnaks , it works .